# A Yixing teapot?

Tags: names

I have had this teaset for a number of years not really knowing much about it.

I have been told it comes from the purple clay teapot museum as a limited edition of 100. I was informed that the mark on the lid is the mark of Jiang Yong, who may have given approval of the set but she was not the maker. Military green was a 20th century innovation.

Can someone tell me what the marks are in English? I was told that the mark on the base said "made in Yixing China" - is that correct?

I look forward to your response.

Also I have acquired two other teapots and a couple of bronze items which I will post on here soon.

Thank you.

https://ibb.co/yk1wb3B
https://ibb.co/QpyyHnq
https://ibb.co/99Nhfh7
https://ibb.co/n6zQJ0L
https://ibb.co/NWtYJSz

Comment: The 2nd is 中國官窰.

Comment: my web browser (safari on ios) gives “**deceptive website warning**” from the provided links 

Comment: Hello - not sure why you get the warning - I have loaded my pics onto a picture store called imgpp which specifically is used to to load pics in forums. However, I will see if I can load them somewhere else.

Comment: Hello r13 - thank you for the info. Am I right in translating these characters to the English "guan ware" or "official ware"? My other observation via Google appears to point to the Song Dynasty which this is obviously not of that period? So why are these characters here? Is it simply an arbitrary mark for the unknowing West?

Comment: 中國官窰 - these appear to say - middle China official kiln - is that right? Can anyone make better sense to this? Is this a specific official kiln in China - could it be the kiln of number one factory in Yixing?

Comment: https://ibb.co/NWtYJSz - Can somebody tell me if this mark says Jiang Rong?

Comment: I just want to say, that for any actual verification purposes, you should have them evaluated by a teaware or yixing specific expert to authenticate them.  there are many authentic yixing pots that look absolutely nothing like the standard, even the clay can be different.  on the flip side you can have very authentic looking imitations that check all the boxes of what to normally look for.  DO NOT take my word for it, but I don't think any of the marks look similar to jiang rong's.  I have no idea how to tell you which one, but one of your photo's aligns with a modern brand's mark.

Comment: 官窰 is a modern term that refers collectively to the historical kilns that supplied porcelain to the imperial palace during the dynasties of Song, Ming and Qing. Confusingly, in the Southern Song dynasty there was a specific kiln named 官窰. Either way, 中國官窰 cannot possibly refer to a specific kiln. Also, zisha (purple clay) is a different material than porcelain.